# Convert Objects to array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this data:

```
 $scope.data = [
        {
            data1:"1",
            data2:"2"

        },
        {
            data1:"1",
            data2:"2"
        }
      ];
```

I want to output them in console log as:

```
[ [1,2], [1,2] ]
```

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.data = [{
    data1:"1",
    data2:"2"
}, {
    data1:"1",
    data2:"2"
}].map(function (o) {
    return [o.data1, o.data2];

    // or, if you really need the items to be numbers:

    // return [o.data1, o.data2].map(Number);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yao,

Look at Lodash or ngLodash.  Lodash has lots of function that do exactly what you are looking to do. ngLodash is a fork and AngularJS rewrite of Lodash.

https://github.com/rockabox/ng-lodash

https://lodash.com

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Jeff